# Does it gives an hashtag icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design

Im trying to using an hashtag icon for my flutter app.It there anyway to get this icon ?.Maybe in material design ?
I need it as a prefix icon.
Hope anyone can help

Heres my code

```
Container(
                              width: 160,
                              height: 55,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 10),
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: hashtagcontroller2,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: '    Hashtag2',
                                  prefixIcon: ,
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      const Radius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                    ),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 2, color: Colors.black),
```

Comment: please share image or code base for better understanding

Comment: Yes please check my code where the prefix stays there should hashtag icon as prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container(
                width: 160,
                height: 55,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 10),
                child: TextField(
                      controller: hashtagcontroller2,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "#",
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            const Radius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            const Radius.circular(40.0),
                          ),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                        )))),
```

Comment: I need the controller

Comment: I resolve it by editing prefix text thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

There is a hashtag icon in the Icons class (Icons.tag).